# using if statment with regular expressions to know if String contains specified characters or not in java

Tags: java, regex

i have made this code and i don't know what is the problem with it, why the output print " f "??? even that the string contains the specified characters in the regex

```
String s="x^2+x-20"; 
Pattern pattern = 
Pattern.compile("([+-][0-9]*)(([a-z A-Z])\\^2)"); //regex

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

if(matcher.matches()){
   System.out.println("t");
} else {
   System.out.println("f");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex makes `[+-]` not an optional match but rather required. Use the following:

```
"([+-]?[0-9]*)(([a-z A-Z])\\^2)" // java syntax
```

Or as a regex without any java escaping:

```
([+-]?[0-9]?)(([a-z A-Z])\^2)
```

Also use `Matcher.find` rather than `Matcher.match` to find matches that are not the entire string.